# Java program | What I give instead graphics in constructor?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

```
/*If given constructor values draw moving circle
 * But if it does not give him the values ​​draws a line
 */
package samr;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.Graphics;
public class AX{
    public static class panel extends JPanel{
        public int w,c=1;
        public panel(int start,int end){
            int x=start;
            int y=end;
            w=x;
            paint(?,x,y);
        }
        public panel(){
            paint(?);
        }
        public void paint(Graphics e){
            e.drawLine(0,0,500,500);
        }
        public void paint(Graphics g,int x,int y){
                    super.paint(g);
                    if(w<=y){
                        w=w+c;
                        if(w==x||w==y){c=c*-1;}
                        g.drawOval(w,0,50,50);
                        this.repaint();
                    }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        JFrame f=new JFrame("test");
            f.setBounds(100,100,500,500);
        panel p=new panel(100,300);
            f.add(p);
            f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

What I give instead graphics in constructor?

Answer (score 1):

You don't, that's provided by the system, take a look at [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details about how painting works in Swing.

If you want to update the component, then you should call `repaint`

Painting in Swing is done via a passive algorithm, to improve performance, you should never modify the state or call any functionality which could modify the state of the UI from within any paint method, so you should remove the `repaint` call in your `paint` method.

By convention, we are encouraged to override `paintComponent` instead of `paint`, it's safer to do so.

Painting should paint the current state of the component, this means you will need to set some variables to the desired values and call `repaint` for them to updated.